# Get the Allocation Unit Size from NTFS disk

Tags: windows, ntfs

I need to find out the "Allocation Unit Size" selected when a particular hard-disk was formatted.

It doesn't appear in the properties information for the drive.

Is there any easy way to get this information?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [fsutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788080(WS.10).aspx) command:

```
fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo [drive letter]
```

You'll have to run this command with administrator privileges.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Now that powershell has caught up and has fledged out a little bit you can run this code in a powershell window:

`Get-Volume  | Format-List AllocationUnitSize, FileSystemLabel`

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to go through all that. make a .txt file with 1 character in it so it isn't 0  bytes, then copy it to the drive. when you look at properties it will have a "size on disk" which you will find is the allocation unit size, because that's the smallest amount it can occupy.